# Removing subset of files in list.file

Tags: r

I am adapting a function written by another user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624977/how-can-you-crop-raster-layers-in-r-in-a-batch-and-change-projection), wherein a series of raster files can be batch cropped.  The function was originally written for .asc files, however I intend to use it for .tif files, which were produced en masse using pyModis (python package; not super relevant).

Right now, `filenames` under the original `list.file()` function is:

```
 [1] "./FILE_mosaik_DOY.tif"      "./FILE_mosaik_DOY.tif.xml" 
 [3] "./FILE_mosaik_EVI.tif"      "./FILE_mosaik_EVI.tif.xml" 
 [5] "./FILE_mosaik_NDVI.tif"     "./FILE_mosaik_NDVI.tif.xml"
 [7] "./FILE_mosaik.tif"          "./FILE_mosaik.tif.xml"     
 [9] "./FILE_mosaikb.tif"         "./FILE_mosaikb.tif.xml"    
 [11] "./ReferenceRaster.tif"
```

I want for it to be:

```
 [1] "./FILE_mosaik_DOY.tif"      "./FILE_mosaik_EVI.tif" 
 [3] "./FILE_mosaik_NDVI.tif"     "./FILE_mosaik.tif"
 [5] "./FILE_mosaikb.tif"         "./ReferenceRaster.tif"
```

The original code uses the following line to bring define the files that will be cropped in a batch:

```
  filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.asc", full.names=TRUE)   #Extract list of  file names from working directory
```

However because I want to use tif files instead, I am using the line below.

```
  filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.tif", full.names=T)   #Extract list of  file names from working directory
```

EXCEPT: There are also .xml files in my working directory that include a .tif extension.  Therefore, `filenames` includes such files as `"./FILE_mosaik_EVI.tif.xml"`. I want to include only the tif files in `filenames`.

I have tried to remove the .xml files two ways.  First, I attempted to use `rm()`, however because `filenames` is a character and not a list (at least I think this is the reason) things didn't work out right and I ended up with a `NULL` `filenames` object.

```
  filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.tif", full.names=T)   #Extract list of  file names from working directory
  filenames <- rm(pattern="*.xml", list=filenames) #Remove the .xml files automatically produced in pyModis
```

I also tried to specify that I don't want .xml files in the original argument

```
  filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.tif" && !="*.txt", full.names=T)   #Extract list of  file names from working directory
```

but that didn't work either.  Unfortunately, many of the existing questions on stackoverflow deal with `list.files()` failing to find enough files, rather than too many...

How can I achieve a `filenames` object that includes *only* the .tif files?

Comment: Use `list.files(pattern="\\.tif$", full.names=T)`. The `pattern=` parameter takes a regular expression, not a file glob. The syntax is different.

Comment: Definite duplicate of @beetroot link above

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$` sign to specify end of the string:

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern="\\.tif$", full.names=T)
```